# Couldn't not able to establish two-way SSL connection

Tags: ssl

Using plain java client i'm trying to connect to other webserver, It works on standlone but when i deploy on weblogic and try to connect it give below error.

Server :weblogic 10.3

Full stack trace of SSL: with below stactrace it easily sounds that handshake is happening but again its trying to connect and failing .please suggest me where i'm doing wrong.

code snippet i'm using :

FileInputStream fisjks = null;

```
        FileInputStream fisTrusted = null;

        String keyStoreType = "jks";

        String passphrase = "password";

        String passphraseTrusted = "password";

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);

        fisjks = new FileInputStream("C:/CFC/Certs/client.jks");

        ks.load(fisjks, passphrase.toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");

        kmf.init(ks, passphrase.toCharArray());

        KeyStore ks1 = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);

        fisTrusted = new FileInputStream("C:/CFC/Certs/clientTruststore.jks");

        ks1.load(fisTrusted, passphraseTrusted.toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance("PKIX");

        tmf.init(ks1);

        SSLContext sslc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");

        sslc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        HttpsTransportInfo https = new HttpsTransportInfo();

        https.setKeyManagers(kmf.getKeyManagers());

        https.setTrustManagers(tmf.getTrustManagers());
```

**error stack trace:**

> found key for : 1 chain [0] = [ [   Version: V3   Subject:
>   EMAILADDRESS=ravi-kumar.gullapalli@db.com, CN=dbsinlt3767, OU=deutsche
>   bank, O=deutsche bank, L=sg, ST=sg, C=sg   Signature Algorithm:
>   SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
>
> Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits   modulus:
>   144592527724012074845004082487794424487354455673579096476940872358533141438065735825819894128056692571922940458543755331194643176374687100664359963995916933269788855991350833527371185749001888440965012790605437863243747901365797345245355690011955852557580366177837112034836139958497356357064447873318654927713
>   public exponent: 65537   Validity: [From: Sun Mar 13 17:23:02 SGT
>   2011,
>                  To: Wed Mar 07 17:23:02 SGT 2012]   Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=ravi-kumar.gullapalli@db.com, CN=dbsinws3283, OU=deutsche
>   bank, O=deutsche bank, L=sg, ST=sg, C=sg   SerialNumber: [    1001]
>
> Certificate Extensions: 4 [1]: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.13
>   Criticality=false Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string = 0000:
>   04 1F 16 1D 4F 70 65 6E   53 53 4C 20 47 65 6E 65  ....OpenSSL Gene
>   0010: 72 61 74 65 64 20 43 65   72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74  rated
>   Certificat 0020: 65                                                 e
>
> [2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false SubjectKeyIdentifier [
>   KeyIdentifier [ 0000: 75 87 47 BE 09 C0 D9 C7   4F FB 5F 57 1D F7 77
>   99  u.G.....O._W..w. 0010: CF 12 FB DB
>   .... ] ]
>
> [3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
>   KeyIdentifier [ 0000: 96 83 10 39 C4 C0 8F 54   5E 0F 85 A0 9C D4 85
>   71  ...9...T^......q 0010: FC 55 39 9A
>   .U9. ]
>
> ]
>
> *** main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2 [Raw write]: length = 7 0000: 15
>   03 01 00 02 02 2E                               ....... main, called
>   closeSocket() main, handling exception:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate
>   found     at
>   weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl.throwServiceException(ServiceImpl.java:174)
>     at
>   weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl.loadWsdlDefinition(ServiceImpl.java:485)
>     at weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl.(ServiceImpl.java:119)    at
>   com.db.luup.InvoiceAgentService_Impl.(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.db.mobile.test.LuupMobileClientTest1.main(LuupMobileClientTest1.java:78)
>   Caused by: weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlException: Failed to read wsdl file
>   from url due to -- javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate
>   found     at
>   weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlReader.getDocument(WsdlReader.java:313)    at
>   weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlReader.getDocument(WsdlReader.java:305)    at
>   weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlSchema.parse(WsdlSchema.java:136)  at
>   weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlSchemaImport.parse(WsdlSchemaImport.java:99)
>     at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlSchema.parse(WsdlSchema.java:116)     at
>   weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlSchema.parse(WsdlSchema.java:73)   at
>   weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlTypes.parse(WsdlTypes.java:165)    at
>   weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parseChild(WsdlDefinitions.java:520)
>     at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlExtensible.parse(WsdlExtensible.java:98)
>     at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:468)
>     at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:403)
>     at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:389)
>     at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlFactory.parse(WsdlFactory.java:79)    at
>   weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlFactory.parse(WsdlFactory.java:66)     at
>   weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl.loadWsdlDefinition(ServiceImpl.java:476)
>     ... 3 more Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate
>   found     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1611)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:187)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:181)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1035)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:124)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:516)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:454)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1112)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1139)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1123)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1049)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
>     at
>   weblogic.wsee.util.is.InputSourceUtil.loadURL(InputSourceUtil.java:100)
>     at
>   weblogic.wsee.util.dom.DOMParser.getWebLogicDocumentImpl(DOMParser.java:118)
>     at weblogic.wsee.util.dom.DOMParser.getDocument(DOMParser.java:65)
>     at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlReader.getDocument(WsdlReader.java:311)
>     ... 17 more Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No
>   trusted certificate found     at
>   sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.buildTrustedChain(SimpleValidator.java:330)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:110)
>     at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)    at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1014)
>     ... 32 more

Answer (score 2):

The server didn't trust the client certificate, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If the error stack is from the client application, then the file `C:/CFC/Certs/clientTruststore.jks` must have the CA certificate for the server certifcate's Issuer.

"No trusted certificate found". The client cannot verify the server's certificate since a matching CA certificate is not found in the truststore.